# How to use callback_url in razorpay intergration?

Tags: callback, response, razorpay

I want to log all failed and success response of payment. Handler option return payment id in the success case and nothing in the failure case. How to log failure payment id?

```
  var options = {
    "key": "API_KEY",
    "amount": "2000", // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": "Product",
    "callback_url":"http://myweb.com/process.php",
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "image": "https://myweb.com/images/image.png",
    "handler": function (response){
          alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    },

    "prefill": {
        "name": "Harshil Mathur",
        "email": "harshil@razorpay.com"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};

    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

    document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: You have already received two answers pointing you to the webhooks section. I think that your question is actually unclear. Either you have missed the fact that payments are inherently asynchronous and that you won't have an HTTP callback, in which case the webhooks documentation should indeed help you. Or you have a webhook in place and have an issue with the events you are receiving there, with a missing payment id maybe. In that case, please provide more information about the issue so we can better help you.

Answer (score -1):

There is a concept called **webhook** in razorpay

You can get every response to that hook and you can capture anything from there

Please goahead [Razorpay webhook](https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/)

Comment: Consider adding some solution rather than just providing a link of the documentation.